# Can't remove child from the stage - if(stage.contains(child1)){removeChild(child1);} doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

It may sound stupid, but how can I remove a definite child from the stage?
e.g.

```
function giveMeResult(e:MouseEvent):void
{

if(stage.contains(result))
    {removeChild(result);}

    addChild(result); // this part works fine, but it adds one over another
}
```

it adds one result on the top of the previous one.

I want the function "giveMeResult: to remove "result" if is on the stage and add a new one.

UPDATE:***
result is a TextField, and result.txt ="" changes from time to time ...

```
trace (result.parent); /// gives  [object Stage]
trace (result.stage); /// gives[object Stage]

trace (result.parent != null && result.parent == result.stage); // gives true
```

when

```
result.parent.removeChild(result);
```

is written without if statement - gives error *TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.*

when written inside:

```
if (result.parent !=null && result.parent == result.stage)
{
result.parent.removeChild(result);
}
```

nothing happens and new child is added on the top of the previous one.

Thanks to all!!!
The result is simple :)
All I had to do is just change result.txt without even removing it from the stage :)

Comment: Given the amount of replies I think you need to look at other parts of your code. I think it's likely that the variable result changes and that's why you can't remove it properly. The function giveMeResult first tries to remove result and then add the same variable to the stage again, but it fails and adds a new instance. That indicates that somewhere you've change the reference to result and when you try to remove it, nothing happens. Since it wasn't on the stage in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is just change result.txt without even removing it from the stage

Answer (score 2):

You need to type `stage.removeChild(result);` and subsequently `stage.addChild(result);`

Edit:

Looking at a function similar to yours:

```
private function func(e:Event) : void {
    if(stage.contains(result)) {
        stage.removeChild(result);
    }

    stage.addChild(result);
}
```

The only way this would add a new instance of the TextField `result` to the stage, without removing the old one, would be if result has changed. See this flow of execution:

```
var result : TextField = new TextField();

// An event occurs and func get's called.
// now result will be added to stage.

result = new TextField();

// An event occurs and func get's called again
// This time the stage.contains(..) will return false, since the current result
// is not actually on stage. This will add a second TextField to the stage.
```

Comment: i have written:

if(stage.contains(result)){
  stage.removeChild(result);
 }
 stage.addChild(result);

and it doesn't work, it gives error

Answer (score 1):

If I am clearly understood what you want, then this code can help you:

```
if (result.parent != null && result.parent == result.stage)
{
    // stage itself contains result
    result.parent.removeChild(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for [DisplayObjectContainer.contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29):  "Grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on each return true."

So contains means anywhere on the display list, not just direct children.  What you want is the parent check Manque pointed out, or simply to remove result from anywhere it might be:

```
if (result.parent) {result.parent.removeChild(result); }
```

Though oddly, addChild(result) will automatically remove it from its previous parent - a DisplayObject can only be at one place in the DisplayList at a time, so I'm not sure why you're seeing multiple results...

Is it possible that the "result" you've passed in isn't the result that's already on the stage?

Comment: I was running into a similar situation where `object.contains(class name)` would pass, but `object.removeChild(class name)` failed because there was a grandchild of `object` that contained the class I was trying to remove.  
  
So instead, I gave the class object a name and checked for its existence:  
   `if(this.object.getChildByName("foo") != null)`  
  
Then used `object.removeChild(class name)...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
MovieClip(root).removeChild(result)
```

[EDIT]

```
function giveMeResult(e:MouseEvent):void{
  if(result.parent != null && result.parent == result.stage){
    stage.removeChild(result);
  }

   stage.addChild(result); 
}
```

Comment: The function you are trying to access stage is that in a class or on the main timeline?

Comment: it gives [object MainTimeline]

Comment: Now try and trace( result.parent ) lets verify its on the main timeline.

Comment: I have written in the update of my question:

*** trace (result.parent); /// gives  [object Stage]*** 
trace (result.stage); /// gives[object Stage]

trace (result.parent !=  null && result.parent == result.stage); // gives true

Comment: Updated my answer please try it